# How do I whitelist a directory in .gitignore and blacklist a file inside it in ~/.gitignore?

Tags: git, configuration, gitignore, home-directory

There are many questions on this topic, but none involve `~/.gitignore`.

---

I have a strange project with a top-level project directory—call it `project/`—full of garbage, but with at least one important subdirectory—say `project/feedme/`.  I'd like to `.gitignore` everything in `project/`, but un`.gitignore` `project/feedme/` and its contents.  This is easy with a negated pattern:

```
project$ cat .gitignore
/*
!/feedme/
```

I have a file `project/feedme/.exrc` which I would like to ignore.  Being a `vi` user, I use `.exrc` files for local editor settings often, and so I have an entry in my `~/.gitconfig` (specified by the `core.excludesFile` Git setting):

```
project$ cat ~/.gitignore
.exrc
```

Unfortunately `git` seems not to want to reignore `.exrc`:

```
project$ git status -s
?? feedme/
project$ git add feedme/
project$ git status -s
A  feedme/.exrc
```

Why does Git not ignore `project/feedme/.exrc`?

---

#### Edit: This section is wrong, as per [prosoitos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64329737/11939006).  See my edits at the end of this question, as it has not been completely answered.

Why do I think this should work?  The manual page **gitignore**(5) says so:

> Each line in a **gitignore** file specifies a pattern. When deciding
> whether to ignore a path, Git normally checks **gitignore** patterns from
> multiple sources, with the following order of precedence, from highest
> to lowest (within one level of precedence, the last matching pattern
> decides the outcome):
>
> - […]
> - Patterns read from a **.gitignore** file in the same directory as the
>   path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level
>   files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by
>   those in lower level files down to the directory containing the
>   file.  […]
> - […]
> - Patterns read from the file specified by the configuration variable
>   **core.excludesFile**.

Since patterns from `~/.gitignore` are read last, I would have thought that the `.exrc` would be ignored in the end regardless of local `.gitgnore`s.

A possible explanation is that this (again from the **gitignore**(5) manual page, emphasis mine)

> It is
> not possible to *re-include* a file if a parent directory of that
> file is *excluded*.

also applies in its dual form (*not* in the manual page)

> It is
> not possible to *exclude* a file if a parent directory of that
> file is *re-included*.

I would consider this a bug however if this is the case; at least it should be stated clearly in the documentation.

---

P.S.:  My `~/.gitignore` works under normal circumstances, so the problem is not there.

---

#### Edits

Prosoitos is right, the global `~/.gitignore` is read *first*, so the `project/feedme/` subdirectory is re-included *after* `.exrc`s are globally ignored.  However I still face another oddity.

As I understand the documentation now, putting `.exrc` on the last line of my `~/.gitignore` is equivalent (if `project/.git/info/excludes` is empty) to putting `.exrc` on the first line of `project/.gitignore`.  Yet if I do this, `project/feedme/.exrc` is ignored this time!

```
project$ cat ~/.gitignore
project$ cat .gitignore
.exrc
/*
!/feedme/
project$ git ls-files --other --ignored --exclude-standard
.gitignore
feedme/.exrc
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Seems you've answered your own question "It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded." It's stated pretty clearly in the man page for `.gitignore`- Or were you looking for another kind of clarity? Conceptually, it sounds like `.exrc` files do not belong in that folder, or at least that specific exclude patterns could be constructed for the contents of that folder.

Comment: @zrrbite I am trying to _exclude_ the `feedme/.exrc` file, not re-include it as is happening above.  As for local `.exrc` files, they specify local editor settings and very rarely (read: never) need to be committed, which is why I ignore them in `~/.gitignore`.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, getting late! The other way around :) But i'd assume that the same applies. I get your meaning now, that the "reverse" scenario of re-adding something to ignore from a folder that was ignored is not clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: @zrrbite It's getting late here too… I spend too much time thinking about corner cases like these when I should really be working on the content of that Git repo!
I'd agree that "the other way around" applies, it's just that it seems like something that I'd never use.  If I really want to prevent all the content of a subdirectory from being excluded I'd just plop down another `.gitignore` with a `!**` inside.

Answer (score 1):

> Since patterns from ~/.gitignore are read last [...]

No. This is where you got it wrong. The section of the Git manual that you quote:

> Git normally checks gitignore patterns from multiple sources, with the following order of precedence, **from highest to lowest** [...]

means that the global `.gitignore` gets overridden by your local one, not the other way around.

So `!/feedme/` in your local `.gitignore` overrides `.exrc` in your global one. Consequently, `feedme/.exrc` is not excluded.

An easy solution would be to add `.exrc` in your local `.gitignore` file and to make sure that it is below the line `!/feedme/` since:

> (within one level of precedence, the last matching pattern decides the outcome)

---

*Note:*

Admittedly, the expression "order of precedence" can be confusing.

Here, "higher precedence" means that it is "more important than" (so it overrides).

You seem to have understood it in the sense of operator precedence, where "higher precedence" would mean "executed before", which would lead to the opposite result. Hence the confusion.

---

#### *Edit after your edit to the question:*

Now that you have made corrections to your situation, I think that you are correct.

I reproduced your situation, then ran:

```sh
git check-ignore -v feedme/.exrc
```

and I get:

```sh
.gitignore:1:.exrc  feedme/.exrc
```

showing that the exclusion of `.exrc` did not get negated by `!/feedme/`.

I tried to google this and I am also unable to find any documentation on it.

Comment: You are right, thank you.  See my edited post however; something strange is still going on.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand the documentation now, putting `.exrc` on the last line of my `~/.gitignore` is equivalent (if `project/.git/info/excludes` is empty) to putting `.exrc` on the first line of `project/.gitignore`.
> Yet if I do this, `project/feedme/.exrc` is ignored this time!

```
project$ cat ~/.gitignore
project$ cat .gitignore
.exrc
/*
!/feedme/
project$ git ls-files --other --ignored --exclude-standard
.gitignore
feedme/.exrc
```

You have excluded the folder `/feedme/` from the ignore rules, but not its content.
You would need `!/feedme/.exrc` from that file to not be ignored.